# Wordpress query from usermeta?

Tags: wordpress

Let's say I want to display a user's billing address with this SQL:

```
SELECT um.meta_value
FROM wp_usermeta um 
INNER JOIN wp_users u ON u.ID = um.user_id
WHERE um.meta_key = 'billing_address_1' AND u.user_login='1234'
```

I know I can use `$wpdb->get_results($myqueryhere)`, but is there a built-in Wordpress function (which I can't seem to web search) to get stuff from the wp_usermeta table that will look much cleaner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to get data using wordpress built in function then,

use

1. [get_user_meta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_user_meta)
2. [get_usermeta()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_usermeta)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the get_user_meta() function to get user meta data

Try like

get_user_meta($user_id, 'billing_address_1');